# State value is updated one step behind in conditional setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-operator

I'm implementing slider component. When user clicks left or right arrow it changes the scroll value by given `scrollWidth`. I have a problem that with this implementation:

```
const Slider = (props) => {
  const [scrollValue, setScrollValue] = useState(0)
  const [containerDimensions, setWidths] = useState({ offsetWidth: 0, scrollWidth: 0 })
  const [activeLeft, setActiveLeftArrow] = useState(false)
  const [activeRight, setActiveRightArrow] = useState(true)

...

  const checkArrowDisable = () => {
    containerDimensions.offsetWidth + scrollValue < containerDimensions.scrollWidth ? setActiveRightArrow(true) : setActiveRightArrow(false)
    scrollValue > 0 ? setActiveLeftArrow(true) : setActiveLeftArrow(false)
  }

  const scrollRight = () => {
    const scrollWidth = sliderItem.current.offsetWidth
    sliderContainer.current.scrollLeft += scrollWidth
    setScrollValue(scrollValue + scrollWidth)
    checkArrowDisable()
  }

  const scrollLeft = () => {
    const scrollWidth = sliderItem.current.offsetWidth
    sliderContainer.current.scrollLeft -= scrollWidth
    setScrollValue(scrollValue - scrollWidth)
    checkArrowDisable()
  }
```

In `checkArrowDisable` the scroll and container width values are checked to hide/show the left and right arrow. The problem is that with this implementation the state of `activeLeft` and `activeRight` are updating one step after they should.
What's wrong with `checkArrowDisable` function ?

EDIT:

Key thing to solve this problem is to create middle-variable with new updated value and pass it to next function.

```
  const scrollRight = () => {
    const scrollWidth = sliderItem.current.offsetWidth
    sliderContainer.current.scrollLeft += scrollWidth
    const updatedScrollValue = scrollValue + scrollWidth
    setScrollValue(updatedScrollValue)
    checkArrowDisable(updatedScrollValue)
  }
```

then

```
  const checkArrowDisable = (newScrollValue) => {
    containerDimensions.offsetWidth + newScrollValue < containerDimensions.scrollWidth ? setActiveRightArrow(true) : setActiveRightArrow(false)
    newScrollValue > 0 ? setActiveLeftArrow(true) : setActiveLeftArrow(false)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setters are async. So you should not use the suppossed set value in the same function or subfunction. What i mean is :

```
  const scrollLeft = () => {
    const scrollWidth = sliderItem.current.offsetWidth
    sliderContainer.current.scrollLeft -= scrollWidth
    setScrollValue(scrollValue - scrollWidth) # scrollvalue not necessarily updated yet
    checkArrowDisable() # uses scrollvalue which is either updated or not
  }
```

I recommend using a variable for `scrollValue - scrollWidth` and passing into the `checkArrowDisable` function

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkArrowDisable` function isn't necessary since those individual methods can be accomplished in a one-liner in each `scroll` function.

Rather do this:

```
const scrollRight = () => {
  const scrollWidth = sliderItem.current.offsetWidth
  sliderContainer.current.scrollLeft += scrollWidth
  const newScrollValue = scrollValue - scrollWidth
  setScrollValue(newScrollValue)
  setActiveRightArrow(containerDimensions.offsetWidth + newScrollValue < containerDimensions.scrollWidth)
}

const scrollLeft = () => {
  const scrollWidth = sliderItem.current.offsetWidth
  sliderContainer.current.scrollLeft -= scrollWidth
  const newScrollValue = scrollValue - scrollWidth
  setScrollValue(newScrollValue)
  setActiveLeftArrow(newScrollValue > 0)
}
```

The issue was that `useState` hook setters run asynchronously. So when you tried to use `scrollValue` in `checkArrowDisable`, it was still using the previous `scrollValue` before it was updated.

Doing what I recommend above solves this issue.

Comment: That solution caused even two-steps delay in changing state.

Comment: @icelandico It's the exact same as the answer you marked correct. Fine I'll update my answer to what I would have done.